# Elliptic W^{2,p}-estimates for a Neumann problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Consider the  simplest elliptic-Neumann  problem in $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$:
$$
-\Delta u+u=f\quad \text{in   } \Omega, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0\quad \text{on  } \partial \Omega. \tag{EN}
$$
Then the standard $W^{2,p}$-estimate gives 
$$
f\in L^p(\Omega)\Longrightarrow u\in W^{2,p}(\Omega).\tag{W2p}
$$
I blearily remember that $p\geq 1$ in (W2p). Is this indeed required?

Next, for a general elliptic-Neumann problem in $\Omega$:
$$
-\Delta u+c(x)u=f\quad \text{in   } \Omega, \quad \frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0\quad \text{on  } \partial \Omega. 
$$
 What is the (known) mildest (regularity) condition on $c$ so that the $W^{2,p}$-estimate (W2p) holds? In particular, whether $c\in L^q(\Omega)$ (for some $q>0$) would be sufficient to get (W2p)? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Generally, $p\ge 1$ in $W^{k,p}$; otherwise the space is not a normed space and everything falls apart... A missing part of your set-up is the initial assumption on $u$: in what class do you assume it to be? In what sense does $-\Delta u+c(x)u=f$ hold?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. $u\in W^{2,p}$ is a strong solution of $-\Delta u+c(x) u=f$. What I really want is how to derive the $W^{2,p}$-estimate:   $$\|u\|_{W^{2,p}}\leq C(\|f\|_{L^p}+\|u\|_{L^p})$$   In particular, if $c>0$ then $$\|u\|_{W^{2,p}}\leq C\|f\|_{L^p}$$. Of course, if $c\in L^\infty$, these estimates hold. The question is how weak can $c$ be so that those mentioned facts still hold?